# Why images are displayed pixelerate when attribute anyDensity=false in android manifest file for samsung galaxy device?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

same code  anyDensity=false works fine for device with display resolution 320*480, but images are displayed pixelerate in device with display resolution 480*800.

Comment: how do you display those images?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the any density=false attribute set and are building an app that will also run with android 1.5 your app will run in a compatibility mode. This will render your app like it is always displayed on a 320*480 screen and just scale down the resulting pixel measurements.

There should be no need to set any density to false in your manifest.

Comment: How can I use images of size 320*480 on device with 480*800 resolution,

Comment: if the image is set to an imagview you can set the the width and height of the imageview as fill_parent and then set the scaleType of the imagview to fit_center. This however will make your images somewhat blurry.

Comment: I am not using imageView I am just drawing it on canvas. Image gets fit into 320*480 resolution but in 480*800 resolution it left some space at the bottom of the screen. I am using image of size 320*480 and putting it in mdpi drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the real resizing is only done for anydensity=true and dp/dip used as units.

Comment: I kept minSdkVersion = "1" in androidMenifest file but images gets blur. Is it because I my build target is Android 2.0 ?